# ggplot: Combine stacked and dodge in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

As the title suggests, I want to combine stacked and dodge in a barplot. Most answers in Stack Overflow (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409850/generate-paired-stacked-bar-charts-in-ggplot-using-position-dodge-only-on-some)) suggest using facet wrapping. I don't want to do that because I have other graphs that do not use facet wrapping and I don't want the aesthetic to be different. The answer that is the closest to the result I want to achieve is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot/46597859#46597859) one. However, I would like to avoid manually creating data frames for all the dodge values.

A subset of the data I'm using is the following.

```
benchmark <- c("correlation", "correlation", "correlation", "covariance", "covariance", "covariance")
technique <- c("last_value", "dyna", "tage", "last_value", "dyna", "tage")
last_value_predictions <- c(1361, 1336, 453, 1865, 1841, 556)
predictions <- c(0, 25, 908, 0, 24, 1309)
df <- data.frame(benchmark, technique, last_value_predictions, predictions)
```

I want the benchmarks on the x axis. There should be 3 bars for each benchmark, one for each techniques (dodge). And then each bar should have the predictions stacked on top of the last value predictions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you do not like the idea of facets, but you can easily adjust the appearance so that they look like a continuous graph, so maybe you could still consider something like this:

```r
benchmark <- rep(c("correlation", "covariance"), each=3)
technique <- rep(c("last_value", "dyna", "tage"), 2)
last_value_predictions <- c(1361, 1336, 453, 1865, 1841, 556)
predictions <- c(0, 25, 908, 0, 24, 1309)
df <- data.frame(benchmark, technique, last_value_predictions, predictions)

library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, ends_with("predictions")) %>% 
    mutate(technique=factor(technique, unique(technique)),
        name=factor(name, rev(unique(name)))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=benchmark, y=value, fill=name)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    theme_cowplot() +
    facet_wrap(.~technique, strip.position = "bottom")+
        theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour=NA, fill="white"), 
            panel.border=element_rect(colour=NA),
            strip.placement = "outside",
            panel.spacing=grid::unit(0, "lines"), 
            legend.position = "bottom") + 
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "grey"))
```

[image]

**Edit:**
You can, of course, switch `benchmark` and `technique` if you want.

**Edit #2:**
Legend adjustment can be achieved by a small extra hack (not sure why it fails otherwise) and labels can be rotated to clean up the appearance of the image result you posted.

```r
p <- pivot_longer(df, ends_with("predictions")) %>% 
    mutate(technique=factor(technique, unique(technique)),
        name=factor(name, rev(unique(name)))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=technique, y=value, fill=name)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    theme_cowplot() +
    facet_wrap(.~benchmark, strip.position = "bottom")+
        theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour=NA, fill="white"), 
            panel.border=element_rect(colour=NA),
            strip.placement = "outside",
            panel.spacing=grid::unit(0, "lines"), 
            legend.position = "bottom",
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "grey"))
p2 <- p + theme(legend.position = "none")
leg <- as_grob(ggdraw(get_legend(p), xlim = c(-.5, 1)))
cowplot::plot_grid(p2, leg, nrow = 2, rel_heights = c(1, .1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this seems very close to my end goal. Is it possible to have the benchmarks on the x axis instead of the techniques? So for example, correlation would have three bars one for each technique.

Comment: Weirdly I'm not getting the same result as you when I substitute technique for benchmark. See the following links.
https://i.imgur.com/1vDmDcL.png
https://i.imgur.com/qY4Vuz6.png

Comment: Also, why is the legend not centred? I've been trying to fix but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Regarding centering of the legend, see my latest edit for a hack to achieve that.