# ggplot and geom_col with position dodge in R is only plotting the max value in my data, rather than the sum value

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

ggplot(data=enroll2, aes(x=ACTUAL_ENRL, y=DEPT, fill=Term))+geom_col(position="dodge", width = 0.60)

this results in

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZrs9.png)

I need the chart to resemble the following (charted with python):
[python chart - same data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX6o0.png)

Data looks like the following:
[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDdzk.png)

Any Ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are workarounds for this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409850/generate-paired-stacked-bar-charts-in-ggplot-using-position-dodge-only-on-some), but I think ggplot2 is a little awkward with dodged aggregated bars. I'd suggest summing upstream, like `library(dplyr); enroll2 %>% count(DEPT, Term, wt = "ACTUAL_ENRL", name = "ACTUAL_ENRL") %>% ggplot(aes(x=ACTUAL_ENRL, y=DEPT, fill=Term))+geom_col(position="dodge", width = 0.60)`

Comment: By default `geom_col` will not compute the sum for you. Instead try with `stat_summary`, i.e. try  `ggplot(data=enroll2, aes(x=ACTUAL_ENRL, y=DEPT, fill=Term)) + stat_summary(geom = "col", fun = "sum", position = "dodge", width = .6)`

Comment: @stefan thanks, that did the trick, now I know :)